# Addis Ababa: cash vs card usage?

Tags: money, payment-cards, ethiopia, addis-ababa

I am traveling to Addis Ababa for just 5 days. From the viewpoint of safety as well as convinience credit cards seem easier.

But just wanted to check how popular is card usage? Can I get by with cards or should I convert to the local currency?

I find a big difference nation to nation in prevailance of card usage.

Comment: Only 0.29% of Ethiopians have a credit card.  Unless you intend to stay entirely within a 5-star hotel, you will almost certainly need cash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the UK travel advisory:
https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/ethiopia/money

> Ethiopia is largely a cash based society. Credit cards are accepted at
> only a very few outlets in Addis Ababa and it is not normally possible
> to get currency advances against a credit card. International bank and
> debit cards are accepted at major banks’ ATMs in the capital but there
> are very limited banking facilities in most other areas. Make sure you
> have an adequate supply of cash before travelling outside the capital.
>
> If you change foreign currency into Birr, you should ensure that you
> keep your receipt, as without this you are unlikely to be able to
> change any left over money back at the end of your trip.

Hope this answers your question. Don't rely on credit card.

Comment: Thanks! So I suppose my best bet is to get Birr at an ATM at the airport?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Why so? Airport *currency exchanges* are often a rip off, but I've never heard of an airport ATM giving worse rates.